# create Linked server from SQL to Linux cent os

Tags: linux, odbc, linked-server

I have standard edition sql server on windows and I need to create a linked server to a Maridb database that is in Cent OS (Galera cluster). Maridb ODBC or mySQL odbc doesn't seems to work but these odbc works great for connection to mariadb that are there in another windows server.
Do I need to install anything on linux server or do I need specific ODBC for linux on windows?

[image: Can't connect]

Comment: "doesn't seems to work" is not an adequate description of the issue. Do you get an error message? If so, what does it say?

Comment: I have added a picure aove that says can't connect

Comment: A web search for "MySQL error 10060" should give you some ideas on what to check. FWIW it sounds more like a server configuration issue than anything to do with the way your client is set up.